# I can't send files to another computer using the TCP port with python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, socket.io

What I want to do is to send a file from my computer to my friend's computer, but we use different internet sites, so when I send the file, I write his IP address, but it gives a timeout error. His TCP port is open, so everything is correct, but it still doesn't work.

sender bot codes;

```
import socket
import os


def send_file_tcp(file_path, host, port):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((host, port))

        file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
        file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)

        s.sendall(f"{file_name} {file_size}".encode())

        with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
            while True:
                data = file.read(1024)
                if not data:
                    break
                s.sendall(data)


    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = r"C:\Users\saddd\Desktop\ad\a.zip"
    host = "213.238.bla.bla"
    
    port = 55455


    send_file_tcp(file_path, host, port)
```

receiver codes;

```
import socket
import os

def receive_file_tcp(save_path, port):
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.bind(("0.0.0.0", port))
        s.listen()

        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
        
        
            file_info = conn.recv(1024).decode()
            file_name, file_size = file_info.split()
            file_size = int(file_size)

            with open(os.path.join(save_path, file_name), 'wb') as file:
                while True:
                    data = conn.recv(1024)
                    if not data:
                        break
                    file.write(data)
     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    save_path = r"C:\Users\we\Desktop\ww\v5"
    port = 55455

    
    while True:
        try:
            receive_file_tcp(save_path, port)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"exc {e}")
```

Does anyone have any ideas where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: does this code work if you spin-up the receiver on the localhost and set the host on the sender to localhost?

Comment: `file_info = conn.recv(1024).decode()` exhibits a common bug. You hope that exactly what is sent in a single `sendall` will be consumed by a single `recv`, but that's not guaranteed by TCP, and relying on that behavior has to be regarded as a bug.

Comment: If you are not on the same intranet, the server would have to configure their router to "port forward" from the public internet IP to the intranet IP (usually something like 192.168.xxx.xxx).  The client would send to the internet IP and port and the packets would be routed to the intranet IP and port.

Comment: I didn't understand much of what you said. My code works for localhost, but when I type the IP address of the recipient, it doesn't work.

Comment: This may be either because of incorrect IP (dynamic IP address/vpn) or their firewall settings or even the port forwarding at 55455 (the port you have hardcoded)

Comment: Google “port forwarding” for your (or your friend’s) router. It isn’t a Python problem.